# Running Redis on ECS using Fargate

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

In my application, I have use ruby and rails application. The application runs on ngix+passanger. I have also used Redis and sidekiq. I want to run my application on ECS Fargate.

**I have implemented the below steps:**

1. Created Docker image using docker file

- web
- webServer
- Redis
- Sidekiq

2. Push docker image into ECR
3. Create task using Fargate
4. run task on ECS with Fargate

My docker-compose file is as below:

```
version: '3.7' 

services:
  web:
    build: 
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports : 
      -  3000:3000 
    env_file:
      - .env

  webserver:
    build : 
      context: .      
      dockerfile: ./nginx/Dockerfile 
    links: 
      - 'web'
    ports : 
      -  80:80 
    env_file:
      - .env

  redis:
    build : 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./redis/Dockerfile 
    volumes:
      - ../../tmp/db:/var/lib/redis/data
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'

  sidekiq:
    build: .
    command: 'bundle exec sidekiq'
```

While I run the task then I got error like as below:

**Error**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your Fargate task, make sure the Security group allows port 6379. It seems to me that the traffic on his port is not passing through, failing the health checks and making the task unhealthy and removed by the scheduler.

Comment: I have already opened the port 6379 in ECS Task. You can check into an error log file that Redis is ready to accept connection but after some time it will receive SIGTERM and it will be shutdown.

Comment: did you ever figure out how to fix this @shariqmaws ? Having the same issue.

Comment: Also check the outbound access of the connecting container

Answer (score 0):

In general for ECS,things to check

1. The Container HealthChecks themselves are passing. Most of the time this boils down to a `pgrep redis` or `redis-cli ping | grep pong`
2. Load Balancer HealthChecks are passing. It is not simply enough to allow to allow 6379 on the container. You must also allow the Load Balancer Security Group or Subnets traffic.

If it is a health check failure ECS logs will indicate why.

1. In the first case you will see something like "container health checks failed"
2. In the case of load balanced tasks, you will see something like "load balancer health check failed" followed by deregistration of the task.